# Puzzling negative correlation

Tags: correlation, independence

**Question edited with the correct code - apologies**

I have observed a somewhat puzzling negative correlation.

**In code (R) (mathematical formulation below)**

```
set.seed(123)
N=1000
R1=vector('double',N)
R2=vector('double',N)
x=rnorm(100)
for (k in 1:N){
  y1=x+rnorm(100)
  y2=x+rnorm(100)
  X=c(x,x)
  Y=c(y1,y2)
  R1[k]=cor(y1,y2)
  R2[k]=var(X)/var(Y)  
}
cor.test(R1,R2)
```

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  R1 and R2
t = -7.2284, df = 998, p-value = 9.704e-13
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2811533 -0.1633130
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.2230479
```

It turns out that `R1` and `R2` are very close to each other but negatively correlated. This is only the case when `x` is kept out of the loop (i.e. fix across experiments).

Would you know why?

**Mathematical formulation**

Let

\begin{align}
& x_i \sim \operatorname N(0,1),\quad i=1,\ldots,100 \quad (\sim\text{indicates i.i.d.}) \\[6pt]
& y_{1,i} = x_i + u_i, \quad u_i\sim\operatorname N(0,1) \\[6pt]
& y_{2,i} = x_i + v_i, \quad v_i\sim\operatorname N(0,1)
\end{align}

We can arrange these random variables as vectors:

\begin{align}
& \mathbf x = [x_i]_{i=1,\ldots,100} \\[6pt]
& \mathbf y_1 = [y_{1,i}]_{i=1,\ldots,100} \\[6pt]
& \mathbf y_2 = [y_{2,i}]_{i=1,\ldots,100}
\end{align}

And we now create the concatenated vectors as follows:

\begin{align}
& \mathbf X = [\mathbf x, \mathbf x] \\[6pt]
& \mathbf Y = [\mathbf y_1, \mathbf y_2]
\end{align}

It turns out that the Pearson's correlation between $\mathbf y_1$ and $\mathbf y_2$ is very close to $\operatorname{Var}(X)/\operatorname{Var}(Y).$ However, the two are negatively correlated when we repeat the process of realising $y_{1,i}$ and $y_{2,i}$ while maintaining $x_i$ constant across realisations.

Would you know why?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Could you please edit it so someone can run it immediately? Also, please set a seed through `set.seed` so everyone can get the same results.

Comment: $Var(y_1)$, $Var(y_2)$ and $Var(Y)$ should usually be about $1.25$.  $Var(x)$ and $Var(X)$ and $Cov(y_1,y_2)$ usually about $1$.  So $Var(X)/Var(Y)$ should usually about $0.8$.  Meanwhile $Cor(y_1,y_2)$ is $Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y_1)Var(y_2)}$, also usually about $0.8$. And they usually both are, and would typically be even closer if you changed your three $100$s to $10000$s.  But "usually" is not "always", and with all the manipulation and simulation noise there is no reason to suppose the deviations from $0.8$ in the two estimates need usually be in the same direction for individual cases.

Comment: Running your code gives an error.  

     Error: object 'R1' not found

Comment: Your question is unclear: "know why" about what, specifically?  If it's about the negative correlation, note that the correlation between `y1` and `y2` will determined by (accidental) correlation between the errors `y1-x` and `y2-x` while positive correlation will tend to increase the spread of `Y` and negative correlation will decrease it, without affecting the variance of `X`; and there you go: that's a negative relationship.

Comment: @Dave Apologies. Please see above the edited code.

Comment: @Henry, I would like to understand why R1 is negatively correlated to R2. It is not clear to me why they ought to be (mathematically).

Comment: Here R1 and Var(Y)/Var(X) are positively related so it's not surprising to see a negative correlation with the second term inverted.

Answer (score 0):

R2 is supposed to be defined as Var(y)/Var(x) to get a positive correlation. The sample correlation is given by cov(x,y)*sd(y)/sd(x).

Comment: *"The sample correlation is given by cov(x,y)*sd(y)/sd(x)"* looks peculiar to me. Why not *cov(x,y)/(sd(y)*sd(x))*?

Comment: How does this address the question?

Answer (score 0):

- $Var(x)$ and $Var(X)$ and $Cov(y1,y2)$ usually about $1$, with the first two constant through your simulation and almost equal to each other (another run or with a different seed would give a different constant value).
- $Var(y_1)$, $Var(y_2)$, $\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ and $Var(Y)$ are usually usually be about $1.25$ with the last two almost equal.
- So $R_1=Var(X)/Var(Y)$ should usually be about $0.8$.
- and $R_2=Cor(y_1,y_2)=Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ also usually about 0.8.

Empirically you can try

```
plot(R1,R2)
```

to see that they are both not far from $0.8$ and that there is not much relationship between them.  The small negative correlation comes from:

- $\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ and $Cov(y_1,y_2)$ are strongly positively correlated
- $\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ and $Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ are weakly positively correlated (the division in the second term removes most but not all of the correlation)
- $1/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ and $Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ are weakly negatively correlated (the reciprocal of the first term tends to reverse the  correlation)
- $1/Var(Y)$ and $Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ are weakly negatively correlated (replacing the first term with one almost equal to it)
- $R_1=Var(X)/Var(Y)$ and $R_2=Cov(y_1,y_2)/\sqrt{Var(y1)Var(y2)}$ are weakly negatively correlated (multiplying the first term by something which is a positive constant through the simulation does not change the correlation)